# Fullcalendar using variable to add events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am having trouble using eventString to add events to fullcalendar. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var value=<?php echo $_SESSION['calAvail']; ?>;
    console.log(value);
    var eventString = "[{";
    console.log(value.endDate[0].substring(11,16));
    for(var i = 0, max = value.endDate.length; i < max; i++) {
        if( i != value.endDate.length-1) {
            eventString += "title:" + "\"" + value.title[i] + "\", ";
            eventString += "start:" + "\"" + value.startDate[i].substring(11,16) + "\", ";
            eventString += "end: " + "\"" + value.endDate[i].substring(11,16) + "\", ";
            eventString += "dow: [" + value.day[i] + "] },{ ";
        } else {
            eventString += "title: " + "\"" + value.title[i] + "\", ";
            eventString += "start:" + "\"" + value.startDate[i].substring(11,16) + "\", ";
            eventString += "end: " + "\"" + value.endDate[i].substring(11,16) + "\", ";
            eventString += "dow: [" + value.day[i] + "] ";
        }

    }
    eventString += "}]"; 

    console.log(eventString);
    var eventShow = eventString;

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: moment(),
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        events: eventString
    })
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function userInfoChange() {
        window.location = "http://localhost/TisTheSeason/profile_user_edit.php";
    }
</script>
```

So first I am creating a string based off a json that contains the title, start, end fields. My plan was to dynamically pull out the information in the json and then format it so it follows this:

```
[{ "title": "", "start": "", "end": "" }]
```

I did that but I can't seem to put the variable in events:

Comment: It is a json in there, so what do you mean?

Comment: I think you've got some kind of misunderstanding here: why on earth are you building JSON strings by hand here?? fullCalendar doesn't even expect a JSON string directly in the `events` property, it expects either a) a JS array of events, or b) a URL from where it can download some JSON which it will then automatically parse into a JS array, or c) a function which does the same process as b) but using a custom data source. You're using JavaScript to do this, so just create a JS literal array directly.

Comment: P.S. regardless of the above, no matter what context you're working in, there's never a good reason to build JSON strings by hand like this. All programming languages have existing code libraries which can take a variable and serialise it into a JSON object reliably. e.g. in PHP it's `json_encode();`, in JS it's `JSON.stringify()`. This avoids horrible unreadable string concatenation code, and also removes the high likelihood of accidental syntax errors / escaping problems which can result from manual construction.

Comment: Can you help me more, like showing me how you would do it. I am completely lost?

Comment: What part of it is puzzling you? Did you understand any part of my comments? Was there a particular part you didn't understand? Do you understand the difference between JSON and a JavaScript object?

Comment: So here is my json, {"day": ["1", "2"], "end": ["somedate", "somedate"] and so on just imagine it looks like that expect with another key start, and somedate is an actual date. Your comments didn't help me figure out how I can pass it to events:

Comment: I added an answer which hopefully makes it clearer. You seem to know how to use objects and arrays - you inject your PHP Session data as a JS object literal, so it's unclear why you then suddently started created the event data as a string instead of an object/array. My code sample should highlight the distinction to you I think.

Answer (score 0):

In the `events` property, fullCalendar expects to be given either

a) a JavaScript variable - which must be an array containing a series of event objects ([documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-array)), or

b) a URL from where it can download a JSON string which it will then automatically parse into a JavaScript array containing event objects ([documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed)), or

c) a function which does the same process as b) but using a custom data source ([documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function)).

Your code appears to be attempting to implement option a), but instead of creating a JavaScript **array** from your data you are creating a variable containing a **string** instead (i.e. some plain text). The string happens to look like JSON, but it's still a **string**. It is not an array. FullCalendar is not expecting this. It's not a usable data structure. To be usable, first it would have to be *parsed* and turned into an array, before you give it to fullCalendar.

That's normally what you'd do if you implemented option c) (and in option b), fullCalendar will do that part on your behalf), but it doesn't work for option a).

Now...you're using JavaScript to create this variable, so it would make far more sense to simply create the desired JavaScript array directly by declaring it in the code. Using JavaScript to make a string and then parse it back to a JavaScript array again is just a pointless extra step. (Also, building JSON strings by hand like this is very vulnerable to the injection of accidental syntax errors and should never be attempted in any situation. If you actually need to create JSON then use a suitable code library to do so.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value= <?php echo $_SESSION['calAvail']; ?>;
  var eventList = []; //declare an array, not a string!

  for(var i = 0; i < value.endDate.length; i++) {
    var event = { 
      "title": value.title[i], 
      "start": value.startDate[i].substring(11,16),
      "end": value.endDate[i].substring(11,16),
      "dow": [ value.day[i] ]
    };
    eventList.push(event);
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(eventList));

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: eventList
  });
});
```

So all you're doing here essentially is translating the data structure from one format to another. Notice how much cleaner, easier to read (and to test, maintain and debug) it is. Also, the `if/else` within your `for` loop appeared to produce an identical object in either case so it's unclear what the purpose of that was. I removed that test in my version.

`defaultDate: moment()` is also redundant in your fullCalendar declaration - fullCalendar will already show today's date by default ([documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/defaultDate)).